# The PSE School of Enigmatics (Part 1)

Tags: riddle, mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, computer-puzzle

**Update:** I fixed up the second image, making it (perhaps) a little bit easier to crack.

You leap out of your bed. Today's the day!

You check your mailbox, and wow, there it is! The frayed look of the letter could not possibly be in greater contrast to the grandeur of its contents.

You can't believe you actually got the letter. It took you hours; no, days of procrastination on Puzzling Stack Exchange to finally, finally enter the PSE school of enigmatics (or PSE for short).

You look at the letter:

[image: Certificate of Invitation]

But wait, what the bejiggles is this? You find a second scroll, lightly glued to the first:

[image: But wait, a secret letter!]

Oh boy. The hair-tearing will begin a lot sooner than you had anticipated.

**Notes:** Hello Puzzling Stack Exchange! This is part 1 of a "puzzle story" that I plan to tell over multiple puzzles. I hope you enjoy!

Comment: Hmm... Is that professor **R**and **a**l'Thor? ;)

Comment: @Mithrandir "professor" Rand al'Thor is within the scope of the question, but (at this stage) I will neither confirm nor deny this :)

Comment: @Mithrandir I also neither confirm nor deny.

Comment: TIL; that PSE stands for "PSE School of Enigmatics", not "PSE School of Enigmatics School of Enigmatics".

Comment: How do you get >100% in an exam?

Comment: Deus and GPR didn't let you in but this M.J. feller did? Suspicious

Comment: @Sid **You might have been able to tell that there is something unusual about your letter of acceptance.** Perhaps this is what Professor R.A. meant!

Comment: @Sid & think123 I had totally chalked it up to it being a "normalized score".

Comment: @Sid In my first year at university, we had exams where full marks was considered to be 100, corresponding to 4 questions worth 25 marks each perfectly answered, but you could actually attempt as many as you wanted and the best 5 would be counted, so there's a real-world example where getting over 100% was technically possible! (From the second year upwards, only the best 4 questions were counted.)

Comment: I second Sid. I'd like to see some hints and some activity in this puzzle.

Comment: I want to see this solved, hints maybe? (Another bump)

Comment: The second riddle's first words imply `6/a[enter]a5`, which looks kindof like something you'd type, and the puzzle does have the [computer-puzzle] tag.  It also looks related to the score of 65/64.

Answer (score 3):

From Bobsons comment,

```
six
slash
a hole
enter
an alt
five
```

seems to me like 6 characters

```
6
/
0
[enter]
alt
5
```

Not enough rep to comment, just my thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

65/64 seems to point to:

> [How can 64 = 65?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24848/how-can-64-65/24851)

Page 2 is beyond me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Very partial answer here, to try and stimulate some movement on this...

The first portion of the second scroll strikes me as

> Equations to solve.

*"First there was woman. Then there was man. Neither the man nor woman produced monthly blood."*

> These aren't actual people, but instead variables `man` and `woman` to solve for.

*"Woman became one with man,"*

> `woman + man = 1`

*"but along came another woman. Now there was one more than just man and woman."*

> `2*woman + man = (woman + man) + 1 = 2` Solving for each gives `man = 0` and `woman = 1`

*"Man then became one with both women,"*

> A new set of equations to solve? `man + 2*woman = 1`

*"but taking a liking to one woman, he ran off with the woman."* (totally lost here) *"In the end, we are given a situation, in which a man and two women are taken away from two men."*

> `2*man - (man + 2*woman) = ?`

Perhaps we could interpret this part instead as

> pseudocode? I.e. `woman = 1; man = 2;` (First woman, then man), `woman = 1 + man;` (Woman became one with man), etc.

Comment: In the vein of numbers and/or pseduocode, see my [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53371/the-pse-school-of-enigmatics-part-1#comment178900_53371) on the second riddle