# The Numberphile Heist (part 2)

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle

A sequel to [The Numberphile Heist (part 1)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53413/the-numberphile-heist-part-1)

You hear a click, and a slight push reveals the entrance. Looking at what's inside, you laughed at your own naïvety.

Instead of a mountain of brown paper, you're faced with merely another vault. On the door is a QWERTY keypad, and a plaque:

[image: Plaque]

Gosh darnit, Brady protects his brown paper well. Unfazed, you try to figure out what the code could be.

Comment: Is the pattern on the gold part of the frame part of the puzzle?

Comment: @micsthepick HAHAHA I absolutely love your attitude! This puzzle is *nowhere* near as complicated as my other ones! More important should be who this plaque is commemorating, and what those two people mean :)

Comment: Relevant youtube videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gGvyeuDT2Do, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxiTG96QOxw&t=276s

Comment: @micsthepick Those two definitely are relevant!

Answer (score 2):

> I am going to go out on a limb and guess that the password is something involving the word sum or summation.

Goldbach created Goldbachs conjecture which states that "Every even integer greater than 2 can be expressed as the sum of two primes"

Durer was an artist who famously featured a magic square in one of his prints. A magic square is a grid of numbers where the sum  of the numbers in any horizontal, vertical, or main diagonal line is always the same number.

> The thing these two have in common involves summing numbers.

Comment: Very well-researched!