# What’s the big idea, 32.5 does not equal 31.5

Tags: mathematics, visual, geometry

Here’s a visual proof for why 32.5=31.5
[image: 32.5=31.5]

Here’s the [animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrWEg.gif)

This puzzle came *directly* from [Proofs without words](https://mathoverflow.net/a/17347/159287) on Mathoverflow.

**Your Goal:** Explain what’s wrong with the proof and where the “missing square” went! Good luck, this one drove me crazy for a bit!

Comment: I'm almost positive this has been asked before but can't find a duplicate! (If it hasn't, I'm impressed it's lasted out so long - this is kind of a classic...)

Comment: @Stiv I looked too, I expected to find it but didn’t.

Comment: @Stiv. Very similar concept in this very popular question https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24848/how-can-64-65/24851#24851

Comment: @DrD does a similar concept mean a duplicate?

Comment: In this case the answer logic is very similar to the 64=65 question. So it may not be a literal duplicate but close. Just my opinion.

Comment: @DrD I agree the answer logic is very similar, it seems so hard to find a duplicate, I don’t know you all find duplicates so easily.

Comment: You are right. Hard indeed. Unless a couple of key words pop out. But I have noticed that while the OP may not find a duplicate the readers almost certainly will!

Comment: If you look carefully you could see the lines of two triangle at different sections of the squares

Comment: @Jingbothedude Yes indeed ;)

Comment: Ya, after reading the answers I realize it is the same :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red and blue triangles don't have the same '**slope**'.

So while in the first picture there is a '**dent**' in the hypotenuse of the big triangle, in the second one there is a '**bump**'.

That difference equates for the missing square.

Changing a bit the sizes of the pieces involved may help with visualising the illusion here. (sorry about the broken grid)

[image: triangle illusion]

Comment: Aw man, you beat me by like 50 seconds

Comment: Nice clip, it has different triangles but it exaggerates the differences in angles better

Answer (score 2):

It's not technically a triangle because the red triangle's hypotenuse has a different slope compared to the blue triangle's.

Rise over run for blue = 2/5

Rise over run for red = 3/8

These values would be the same if this were a triangle. Therefore, when the shapes are rearranged, the area changes.